# Split one long string by multiple delimeter in shorter string with max len

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lcd

i try to send long strings to a 20x4 LCD Display on the raspberry pi, which means 20 character in 4 lines.

To keep the text readable on the lcd i want to split on

1. whitespace
2. Special character like ',', '.', '!', '?', etc
3. Max line len of 20
4. Max word len of 20

I found some code split strings by word(whitespace) but i cant get further...

```
s = "This is a very long string with many many many many and many more sentences and there is not one character that i can use to split by, just by number of words 1 2 3 12° C 3, ,5 ,6 .7 5 "
l = s.split()
n = 5
[' '.join(l[x:x+n]) for x in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

In this case two words could be **'foobarfoobarfoobar foo'** which is longer than 20 chars.

Comment: What do you mean by line length?

Comment: What happens when a word itself has more than 20 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nice `textwrap` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) brings you the first 90%. It splits mainly on whitespace (not on your special characters). If you really need to split on these ones as well, you can always suffix them with a whitesapce.

```
import textwrap
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=20)
for line in wrapper.wrap(text):
    print line, len(line)
```

Comment: there is a colon missing at end of for loop, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "longlongstuff [...]"
n = s.split() #whitespace
n = n.split(",")
n.flatten() #not sure about this.              transforms matrixes (and 3or more dimensional arrays) into one dimensional ones
n = n.split(".")
n.flatten()
#...
for i in range(len(n)):
    e = n[i]
    if len(e) > 20: #length longer than 20
         n[i] = [e[:20],e[19:]]
 n.flatten()
 "\n". join(n)
```

should work kind of. small psydocode

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to insert a newline at the closest word boundary to 20 characters:

```
In [22]: print re.sub(r"(\b.{,20}\b)",r"\1"+"\n",s)
This is a very long 
string with many 
many many many and 
many more sentences 
and there is not one
 character that i 
can use to split by
, just by number of 
words 1 2 3 12° C 3
, ,5 ,6 .7 5 
foobarfoobarfoobar 
foo
```

if you want to be more specific or add more logic you can also pass a lambda to sub :

```
In [106]: f = lambda x: x.group(1).strip()+",\n"

In [107]: print re.sub(r"(\b.{,20}\b)", f, s).rstrip(",\n")
This is a very long,
string with many,
many many many and,
many more sentences,
and there is not one,
character that i,
can use to split by,
, just by number of,
words 1 2 3 12° C 3,
, ,5 ,6 .7 5,
foobarfoobarfoobar,
foo
```